# Terminal - How to open window at a certain directory

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, fullscreen, textmate

When I open Terminal on Mac, it starts in the root directory. I don't want to have to type cd to change my directory every time I open terminal, I want to be in that directory to begin with.

How do I make terminal start in a specific directory? Also, how do I make terminal always start full screen and in a particular color?

Also, what is the command to open text mate in terminal?

Comment: To open TextMate either run "open -a TextMate" or install mate, for the latter go to TextMate → Preferences → Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps better belongs on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), but here are two options to start a Terminal session at a particular location:

1. Open Terminal Preferences to the *Settings* section, and in the *Window* tab check the "Run command", and enter `cd yourdirectorypath` in the command field. It will automatically run for any new Terminal window.
2. Edit the `~/.bash_profile` and add the `cd yourdirectorypath` line at the end.

As for starting fullscreen, if you quit Terminal with a fullscreen window open, it will launch that way.

You can set colour schemes in the preferences, there are many built-in "profiles".